# why it gives negative values when finding factorial in C?

Tags: c, recursion, codeblocks, factorial, unsigned-long-long-int

- I have to make a recursive function to find the factorials from 1 to 30.
- The factorial values are correct up to 12. And from 13, it gives wrong values and some of them are negative.
- I used "unsigned long long" but didn't work.
- I use codeblocks as the compiler so I think it only can handle up to a 32-bit integer.
- Here is the code and the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned long int factorial_rec(unsigned long n)
{
  if(n==1) return 1;
  else return factorial_rec(n-1) * n;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;

  for(i=1; i<30; i++)
    printf("%d! = \t%d\n", i, factorial_rec(i));

  return 0;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
1! =    1
2! =    2
3! =    6
4! =    24
5! =    120
6! =    720
7! =    5040
8! =    40320
9! =    362880
10! =   3628800
11! =   39916800
12! =   479001600
13! =   1932053504
14! =   1278945280
15! =   2004310016
16! =   2004189184
17! =   -288522240
18! =   -898433024
19! =   109641728
20! =   -2102132736
21! =   -1195114496
22! =   -522715136
23! =   862453760
24! =   -775946240
25! =   2076180480
26! =   -1853882368
27! =   1484783616
28! =   -1375731712
29! =   -1241513984
```

Comment: Think about the range of values that can be held by the variable type. Unsigned 32-bit can hold `4294967295` but 13! is `6227020800`.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings as well. Passing an int to a function which takes unsigned long should probably give warning.

Comment: @WeatherVane unsigned long long can be use up to ~ 1.845 x 10^19 But it doesn't work

Comment: Code you have not shown does not work. You must be consistent with the data types and format specifiers. `printf` will need `%llu` for `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is how you're printing the results:

```
printf("%d! = \t%d\n", i, factorial_rec(i));
```

The `%d` format specifier expects an `int` argument, but for the second one you're passing in an `unsigned long`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For an `unsigned long` you should use `%lu` as the format specifier.  However, an `unsigned long` is not guaranteed to be big enough to hold a 64-bit number.  For that, you should use `unsigned long long` as the datatype, and use `%llu` to print it.